Clarification needed on the logic of the `.gitignore` file
I seriously need some clarification on how the .gitignore file works in relation to creating a local repo in my GitHub desktop, because I do not believe that this works in the way a human would logically think it would work.
Having created a local repo (my OneDrive folder), after creating and saving a text file named .gitignore, the files included in my .gitignore file continue to be included in the list of files to be committed to my remote repo.
I have even committed the .gitignore file to the remote repo, but no dice. No other files have been committed on this repo.
I don't really understand why this is, because logically speaking, they should not be tracked.
This is my MRE

Creating a .gitingore file.

A .gitingore file was created in the root of the directory, and populated with the following files, which are all straight off of the root directory:
#.gitignore.txt
Apps/
Attachments/
.git
.gitattributes


Opened GitHub Desktop app

File > Add local repository > Navigated to OneDrive directory > Add repository
However, the files in my GitHub desktop continue to be tracked. Is this a known issue of GitHub which the "Hub of Git" have yet to iron out? Because IMHO it really should be a pretty straight-forward, logical thing to do.
The file directory's is as follows:
<OneDrive>/
     Apps/
     Attachments/
     .git
     .gitattributes
     .gitignore
     <Folder/>
     <Folder/>
     <Folder/>

So why is GitHub continuing to ignore the .gitignore file?

Dis you create a ".gitignore" file, or ".gitignore.txt"? You don't want any extension (which Windows may hide from you)!

(1) Take as a friendly advice, try to avoid developing in a OneDrive folder. The git syncing and OneDrive syncing can sometimes cause some issues (2) Correct me if I'm wrong, based on your description, it seems like you have files already being tracked before you create .gitignore. If i'm not wrong, .gitignore says what not to add for tracking, it doesnt magically untrack those that are already tracking.

@LHY they’re untracked. The file was created before the local repo was added.

Can I confirm that the process is like this:  (0) new repo/nothing is tracked (1) create .gitignore, sources files and other folders, (2) commit .gitignore, (3) commit source files?

Can I also check if the problem still exists (1) if it is not in a OneDrive folder, (2) for other means of Git (or does the problem only appears in GitHub Desktop app)?

Make sure your file is named .gitignore not .gitignore.txt
Double check on that since Windows can sometimes be hiding the file extentions. See how to show or Hide Files Name Extension in Windows.
Don't put Git-related files/folders into .gitignore
Your .gitignore should not contain
.git
.gitattributes

as these are folder/files that Git likely needs to function properly and you would want to commit them.
.gitignore is not working the way you may think
From Git Documentation,

A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected; see the NOTES below for details.

And in NOTES:

The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked.

Also indicated in the notes is the solution to untrack files that are already tracked but you no longer wants it tracked:

To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use git rm --cached to remove the file from the index. The filename can then be added to the .gitignore file to stop the file from being reintroduced in later commits.

You may also refer here for a command-by-command on how to fix it.
